# Tee Command to save output in txt file

Tags: c, cmd, tee

I want to copy the output in cmd prompt to txt file. I used the following command:

```
sample.exe /all > sample.txt
```

But the above command shows only the printf statements not showing the scanf. So i moved to tee command. Can anyone provide me the command to save the output file for sample.exe in txt file

Comment: Try [script](http://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/1/script/) if you have it available.

Comment: @pmg - I am not able to get u. I am very new to this concept. Plese tell me with explanation

Comment: `script` saves input and output to a file. I don't know if there is a Windows version.

Comment: There's a [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) version of it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want not only the *output* of your program to show up in a log, but also the *input*.

In this case the simplest way to go would be to have your program *echo* its input:

```
2014-03-17 15:18
User "Foo" called "sample.exe foo bar 42".
Please enter your phone number:
User input: "555 1234 999"
Processing "foo bar 42"...
```

You get the idea. If input is important, *print* it to terminal. If that makes your program chatty, only print it if the `-v` or `--verbose` command line option is given.

Comment: @Balaji: OK, seems your problem is not with logging input, your problem is basic programming... that's something you need a book or a good tutorial for, not a Q&A website like this one...

Answer (score 0):

The question is not entirely clear, so I'm making some guesses here.  I believe you are saying that the command `sample.exe` is reading input which you are generally providing interactively (ie, you type it into the same terminal from which the command was executed.)  In that case, it is *not* merely the output of the program that you want to save in the file, but the input as well, and you probably want that interleaved with the output in the same order that you see it when you invoke the program.  In that case, `pmg`'s comment is accurate, and you want the `script` command.  If you have `script` just do:

```
$ script sample.txt     # start a new shell, saving to sample.txt
$ sample.exe /all
$ exit                  # close the shell
```

Comment: I used the above code but its also not displaying the scanf values.

Comment: What do you mean by "the scanf values"?  That phrase has little meaning.  Do you mean the values returned by the call to scanf that are made inside the program?

Comment: The value that is given as input in c program